# Scala equivalent code for Jackson's @JSONView

Tags: java, json, scala, serialization, jackson

How could I write the Scala equivalent code for the below Java snippet that uses @JSONView.
I'm using Scala and Jackson's JSON. I have a requirement were in certain fields need to be dynamically included or excluded based on certain condition - during serialization. Based on Jackson's wiki, @JSONView seems to be a good option - but I have not been successful in getting the scala equivalent.

```
public class Employee {

public static class All { }
public static class View1 extends All { }
public static class View2 extends View1 { }
public static class View3 extends All { }

@JsonView(All.class)
public Long empid;

@JsonView(View1.class)
public String name;

@JsonView({View2.class, View3.class})
public String addr;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The direct Scala equivalent would look something like this:

```
object Employee
{
  class All
  class View1 extends All
  class View2 extends View1
  class View3 extends All
}

class Employee
{
  import Employee._

  @JsonView(Array(classOf[All]))
  var empid: Long = _

  @JsonView(Array(classOf[View1]))
  var name: String = _

  @JsonView(Array(classOf[View2], classOf[View3]))
  var addr: String = _
}
```

This conversion doesn't take advantage of any Scala-specific Jackson support; it should work as-is with or without the [Jackson Scala module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala) installed.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to try this out.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think to add the Array[] around the classOf[]

Comment: Correction - Array() !